# Python package installed as non root user return command not found when ran using sudo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, debian, pypi

I'm studying how to create Python packages and I'm facing a problem.

I have a bash script to create Apache virtual hosts and I decided to rewrite it using Python. So far so good.

I used to run my bash script like this

```
$ sudo vhost myvhost.localhost myuser
```

And I want to do the same with the Python version. I installed the package using pip as non root user and everything goes fine. When I try to run it, I got a command not found.

I had the same problem with my bash scripts, I store them in $USER/bin so I added this directory to secure_path in /etc/sudoers and problem solved.

Currently, I'm installing my package as root

```
$ su -
$ pip3 install vhost
```

And then I can run the command as non root without the **command not found** message.

The question is: How is the Python way of solving this issue?

You can see my code here https://github.com/felipebool/vhost
and I'm developing in a Debian machine.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have two versions of `python` installed? may be 2.x and 3.x. `pip3` is for 3.x while `pip` is for 2.x. Also you may need to fix python path between root and non-root. Check if they are different.

Comment: No, I do not have two versions of Python.